# Calculate the percentage of accuracy with which user made the assigned sound

Tags: signal-analysis, sound, array-signal-processing

I want to design a web-app for my cousin who is 2 years of age in which i have implemented a functionality in which when an image is clicked some sound gets played and the user has to make the same sound which gets recorded.

For eg-If i click on image of "Apple" the sound made is "A for Apple".Now the user has to say those words which get recorded.
Now I want to calculate the percentage of accuracy with which the user spoke.I want to know how can i know the accuracy percentage.
I read some research papers and did some online research and I have come to know across is that i will have to use DTW or MFCC and other research papers it was asked to use both.
I want to know what resources should i refer to and what parameters of sound signal should i use for the purpose of knowing the accuracy

Comment: That is a super cool idea!

Comment: I think you shouldn't be reading papers right now, though. Get a textbook about speech processing – there's much established knowledge there! (and a textbook is better to read than the original papers - it's knowledge, sorted, condensed and explained, whereas papers tend to present something *new*. If you read a new paper in a field that is somewhat mature, it will inherently be a bit "exotic", because all the "common knowledge" things have already been tried out.)

Comment: Be a bit careful though: you'll end up training a very complex neural network (your cousin) that can trivially overfit to what is presented as correct answer :)

Comment: I know it's not helpful, but on iOS you could make such app in SwiftUI fairly easily. 
If you want to make a **very** simple classifier then MFCC's + DTW is the simplest way to go. 
Alternatively, you can use ready speech recognition model/API to get the exact translation.

Comment: A person who is 2 years of age has a different opinion on what "A for Apple" should sound like than an adult. The classifier would have to get a bit creative so that it correctly interprets the 2yo sounds. How this enrichment is done is going to be interesting in this application...

Comment: DTW on MFCC and comparing with reference sounds might do OK. Buuut possibly only if the reference sounds are also spoken by a two-year old. So you likely need to collect some data. And depending on how far may words and similarity of words are, it might get tricky. Apple and Orange pretty easy to separate. "No" and "none" maybe not

Comment: Btw. "Was it the correct word" (with a known set of words) is a considerably easier task than "was the word pronounced well". Both for machines and (young) humans! So might want to get that working first.